# Sonata Admin one to many relationship list

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

In my Symfony project I have 2 Entities. One is Blog and another is Post. In such a way there is an one to many relationship from Blog to Post. Now when I try to add a post to a blog in SonataAdmin => Blog => Edit Page, it shows all of posts that I have recently created (which are irrelevant to current blog). I want there be only a button named add new for adding posts and a list of added posts to blog.
This is my current code:

```
class BlogAdmin extends Admin{
        protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
        {
            $formMapper
                ->add('posts', 'sonata_type_model', array('multiple' => true, 'property' => 'title', 'label' => 'Image', 'required' => false))

            ;
        }

}
```

Would you please to tell how?

```
FstQst\WebBundle\Entity\Blog:
    type: entity
    table: blog
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

    manyToMany:
        posts:
            targetEntity: Post
            joinTable:
                name: post_blog
                joinColumns:
                    post_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    blog_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
           orphanRemoval: true
```

Comment: Provide your mapping information

Comment: I edited my post. Is it enough?